# ibm_db2 PHP7 Nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, db2

Estou com problemas pra iniciar a extension ibm_db2 no meu servidor.

É um Ubuntu Server 16.04, rodando PHP7.0 + Nginx

Fiz a instalação com

`pecl install ibm_db2`

Adicionei as estradas no *etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini*

```
extension=ibm_db2.so
```

Porém no phpinfo() não aparece que foi adiciona a extension

Alguma ideia do que posso fazer ?

EDIT

Resolvi o problema adicionando a extension de outro modo

```
echo "extension=ibm_db2.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ibm_db2.ini

ln -sf /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ibm_db2.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-ibm_db2.ini

ln -sf /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ibm_db2.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ibm_db2.ini

service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deu um restart no fpm ?
- restart php7.0-fpm

Da uma olhada em: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm)

Comment: Sim, ele restart normal.

Comment: Ta usando qual so ?